# Invite Friend Request using new Android SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, fbdialogs

I am using the new Facebook SDK **3.0** that just released on Android. I want to let the user **invite his/her friends to the app**.

However, in the new SDK you do NOT create a **new Facebook** object with the App ID. You extend the **FacebookActivity** as given in the tutorial: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/

Hence, I could not use the reference material provided to send invites to friends since there is no facebook object to call the **dialog method** on.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/send-requests/

I've already setup the **Friend Picker UI** and can get GraphUser objects that the user selected. 
http:// developers(dot)facebook(dot)com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/show-friends/

But, I can't figure out how to **invite the friends that the user has selected**.

Does anyone know how to invite friends in the **new SDK**? Would you be using the **FbDialog** class? If so, what is the **url string** that needs to be provided? (I tried using "**apprequests**", but that didn't work)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use com.facebook.widget.WebDialog class for this:

```
WebDialog dialog = new WebDialog.Builder(myActivity, mySession, ...).build();
dialog.show();
```

Also see helper classes WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder and WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder that make it easier to build these dialogs.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize doing it the old way was not deprecated.

Comment: This method is deprecated, in fact instantiating the "Facebook" class is deprecated. Please provide another solution.

Comment: Updated instructions to reflect the new API in the final bits.

Comment: Hi,In old i will add like this params.putString("to", userIDString);
params.putString("message", Message);. now where i will give the Friends user Id??

Comment: To add parameters, after you create a new WebDialog.Builder(), call builder.getParameters(), add any parameters you want to the returned Bundle, and then call builder.build() to create the WebDialog.

Answer (score 8):

Try this link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/send-requests/

```
    private void sendRequestDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "Learn how to make your Android apps social");
    WebDialog requestsDialog = (
        new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                    FacebookException error) {
                    final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                    if (requestId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Request sent",  
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Request cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            })
            .build();
    requestsDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Hi,In old i will add like this params.putString("to", userIDString);
params.putString("message", Message);. now where i will give the Friends user Id??

Comment: @Ramachandran use setTo(String id) method. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder